# How to get a list of programs running with nohup

Tags: linux, shell, centos, nohup

I am accessing a server running CentOS (linux distribution) with an SSH connection.
Since I can't always stay logged in, I use "nohup [command] &" to run my programs.

I couldn't find how to get a list of all the programs I started using nohup.
"jobs" only works out before I log out. After that, if I log back again, the jobs command shows me nothing, but I can see in my log files that my programs are still running.

Is there a way to get a list of all the programs that I started using "nohup" ?

Comment: Found an excellent article that can help with the question: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-out-what-processes-are-running-in-the-background-on-linux/. Most importantly, it's helpful if you can interpret the output of the ps command, especially the stat column. If you don't, go read the article NOW ;-)

Answer (score 158, accepted):

When I started with `$ nohup storm dev-zookeper` ,

**METHOD1 :** using `jobs`,

```
prayagupd@prayagupd:/home/vmfest# jobs -l
[1]+ 11129 Running                 nohup ~/bin/storm/bin/storm dev-zookeeper &
```

*NOTE: `jobs` shows nohup processes only on the same terminal session where `nohup` was started. If you close the terminal session or try on new session it won't show the `nohup` processes. Prefer METHOD2*

**METHOD2 :** **using `ps` command.**

```
$ ps xw
PID  TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
1031 tty1     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
10582 ?        S      0:01 [kworker/0:0]
10826 ?        Sl     0:18 java -server -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/root/bin/storm -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib -Dsto
10853 ?        Ss     0:00 sshd: vmfest [priv]
```

TTY column with `?` => `nohup` running programs.

**Description**

- TTY column  = the terminal associated with the process
- STAT column = state of a process

  - S = interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
  - l = is multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL pthreads do)

**Reference**

`$ man ps` # then search `/PROCESS STATE CODES`

Comment: **Method 2 does not list the programs that were started with `nohup`**. It lists the processes that are not attached to a TTY, which is a completely different thing: processes started with `nohup` remain attached to their parent TTY until it is closed; processes that are not attached to a TTY were not necessarily started with `nohup`. That is, method 2 lists, *among other* processes, *some of* the programs running with `nohup`.

Comment: jobs doesn't work for me, only works for a same ssh session, if I disconnect and connect again it no longer lists the previously listed running nohup process

Comment: `$ ps xw` work for me.

Answer (score 40):

Instead of `nohup`, you should use `screen`. It achieves the same result - your commands are running "detached". However, you can resume screen sessions and get back into their "hidden" terminal and see recent progress inside that terminal.

`screen` has a lot of options. Most often I use these:

To start first screen session or to take over of most recent detached one:

```
screen -Rd
```

To detach from current session: <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>

You can also start multiple screens - read the docs.

Comment: Seems to be a good alternative to me. I also found out that i could find the PIDs with "ps auwx"

Comment: Question clearly asks *Is there a way to get a list of all the programs that I started using "nohup"?*, yet this answer doesn't even slightly address the question.  Why is it accepted?

Comment: Because back in 2013, it was the only answer that helped.

Answer (score 31):

If you have standart output redirect to "nohup.out" just see who use this file

```
lsof | grep nohup.out
```

Comment: That is a smart way. But in my case this returns no results. Although I'm sure that the nohup command is still runing, and it's using the nohup.out file.

Comment: It's ok in all TTY, but show double process for each nohup!

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z. from `man lsof`: "In general threads and tasks inherit the files of the caller, but may close some and open  others,  so lsof always reports all the open files of threads and tasks." I couldn't find information on nohup in its man, but it seems it uses two threads, not one.

Comment: Won't work if the output is redirected to some other files

Answer (score 10):

You cannot exactly get a list of commands started with `nohup` but you can see them along with your other processes by using the command `ps x`.  Commands started with `nohup` will have a question mark in the TTY column.

Comment: "ps x" didn't help, but I found out that "ps auxw" does.

Answer (score 10):

You can also just use the top command and your user ID will indicate the jobs running and the their times.

`$ top`

(this will show all running jobs)

`$ top -U [user ID]`

(This will show jobs that are specific for the user ID)

Comment: Additionally, the nice thing about this is that it stays on your console so you can watch the job and know when it finishes

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo lsof | grep nohup.out | awk '{print $2}' | sort -u | while read i; do ps -o args= $i; done
```

returns all processes that use the nohup.out file

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience, I prefer the `top` command, see [javapoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/linux-top#:%7E:text=The%20top%20command%20displays%20all,stands%20for%20table%20of%20processes.) for more examples how to use `top`. As user [Jcrow06](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26011045/22082887) already suggested, running `top` will show you all running jobs on the server and if one is only interested in the jobs of a specific [userid], one can simply run `top -u [userid]`.

The benefit of running `top` is that all running processes are shown (including nohup processes, even when started in the background), also ones that are not from the current terminal session or from a different user. Furthermore, one can see with `top` how much CPU and memory the task takes and for how long it is already running. Which can be helpful to determine if it is still running correctly.

Note `top` by default orders tasks on CPU usages, but one can adjust the ordering if needed. Furthermore, if you notice unwanted tasks, you can kill them easily by pressing `k` followed by the processID `PID`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34555703)