# jobs find nothing after nohup a script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jobs, nohup

I made a python script running on background:

`nohup python app.py &`

then close the terminal, a few days later, I want to see this job, so I run

`jobs`

there list no jobs, but I'm sure the script `app.py` is still running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jobs` will only give you a list of process running under the [session group](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-10.html) of the bash shell. `nohup` processes run in their own session group. There are a number of simple [commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809134/how-to-get-a-list-of-programs-running-with-nohup) you can run to check if your nohup'd process is still running, the simplest being `lsof | grep nohup` (this command may take a few seconds to run)